# Integrating multiple tawk.to widgets on one page

Tags: javascript, html, dom, code-snippets

I have been trying to integrate multiple tawk.to widgets inside popups,

```
<div id="tawk_xxx"><br></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {},
        Tawk_LoadStart = new Date();
    Tawk_API.embedded = 'tawk_5f96cfd1aca01a168835cf5a';
    (function() {
        var s1 = document.createElement("script"),
            s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s1.async = true;
        s1.src = 'https://embed.tawk.to/xxxx/xxx';
        s1.charset = 'UTF-8';
        s1.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
        s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);
    })();
</script>
```

the problem is when the JS snippet loads, it sets some global variable in the window object that should be cleared to run the Tawk_API again whereas I want to keep both instances running at the same time. I tried using Iframes, the problem with iframes is that the browsers will consider as third party cookies, and the iframe will be blocked if the browser does not allow them
so is there any way around this issue